# How may I reset a buffer index on Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm using [MiniBufExpl](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) to manage buffers.

In my workflow, I usually work on one thing at a time. I'm opening some files, coding, enjoying. Then, I want to clear my workspace to start with new buffers. Today I'm doing `:qa[!]` and opening a new vim.

MBE provides a nice command that deletes the buffer [without closing the window](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/blob/master/plugin/minibufexpl.vim#L1392): `:MBEbd`, an improved `:bdelete`.

I could easily do a small vim function that takes `:buffers` and `:MBEbd` to remove every buffers. 
Thing is, indexes will stay the same. Yes I often use `:b[N]` (where `N` is my buffer index), this is fast with 1 to 6 buffers but becomes painful with  2 figures.

How may I reset a buffer index to improve my workflow?

---

A test case:

```
vim
isomething<ESC>
:enew
ielse<ESC>
:bd!
:enew
:ls
```

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May  9 2015 15:38:59)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.  There was definitely no way up through vim 7.2 - I'm not completely up to date, but I doubt one has been added since then.

Comment: Do you have a technical explanation? I have the feeling that the buffer, even when deleted, is staying in memory.

Comment: The buffer isn't staying in memory after a `:bdelete`, it's just that the deleted buffer numbers are never reused.  In general, Vim just won't reuse a buffer number.

Comment: Is this not considered as a bug? Maybe I should ask on the mail list.

Comment: No, it's not a bug, it's just a feature that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the process of restarting vim easier with sessions.

Save the session with :

```
:mksession!
```

Open a session with :

```
:so Session.vim
```

note : The buffer index will start at 2 (buffer 1 is used to source Session.vim)